# How to make a function that modifies a struct

Tags: c

I'm making a program for putting students grades in an array using a struct as practice for a final. I need to make a function that checks to see if any positions are left in the array and if there is not, the array needs to double in size and then the grade needs to be added to the next available position. If the array has open positions then the grade values should be added to the next available position. grades_array_pos and grades_array_size have to be updated with the correct values whenever a change to the array occurs. Im pretty new to C and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around on how to do this. All of this has to be done using only basic variables, for and while loops, and in a very basic manner.

```
struct student_grades
{
    int student_id; 
    int *grades_array[10];
    int grades_array_pos;
    int grades_array_size;
};
void add_grade(struct student_grades * student, int assignment_grade){

}
```

Comment: Did they give you the initialization code?  e.g. something has to create a student_grades structure and initialize it.

Comment: The professors has code in the vocarium browser that does this. It also holds test cases. We literally just write the function and it is tested when we hit the send button. we can send it unlimited times.

Comment: its shows us the struct above and gives us the beginning of the function you see. We fill out the inside of the function. There is a word document that tells us what i said above as far as what the function should do.

Comment: well, my point is you're going to need to do some testing on your own.  Which means making a student_grades struct (outside of your add_grade() function).  Hmm... I'll throw something in another answer in a bit to get you started.

Comment: Hmm... I'm getting stuck on "grades_array", which appears to be a ten item array of pointers to integer.  Sorry, thought I could help - I could deal with it if it where just "int *grades_array;"  Say, does the vocarium thing show you the results of printf?  Or just "8 of 25 tests passed."

Comment: just the amount of test passed. i added the [10] to grades_array because i thought thats how you made it an array. I figured it had to have a size if i was to be able to double it when needed. I have early class so i wont be back on until tomorrow. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Good to know.  Please post the original struct as-is, no changes :-)  The extra [10] is a step in the wrong direction - I will keep my eye on my message box.  (Basically everything that david-c-rankin said.)

Answer (score 4):

This is a critical, but simple, skill everyone needs to master. The basic approach is to keep variable holding the current number of elements allocated and a counter to the number used. Then loop filling your array. At the *beginning* of your loop, check whether `if (used == allocated)` to determine if a reallocation is needed.

If a reallocation is needed, then using a TEMPORARY pointer, call `realloc` and double the number of elements allocated. Validate that `realloc` succeeded, otherwise, break the loop filling your array, (don't exit the program) as the original pointer to your array still points to the valid data prior to the `realloc` attempt.

If the `realloc` succeeds assign the newly sized block of memory to your original pointer, update the variable with the new count of allocated elements -- and keep going, repeat as necessary. Example:

```
#define NSTRUCT 8    /* initial number of struct to allocate for array */
...
size_t  allocated = NSTRUCT,   /* holds current number of elements allocated */
        used = 0;              /* holds current number used/filled */
struct student_grades *grades = malloc (allocated * sizeof *grades);

if (!grades) {
    perror ("malloc-grades");
    return 1;
}

while (/* loop to fill struct array */) {

    if (used == allocated) {    /* check if realloc needed */
        /* always realloc using a TEMPORARY pointer */
        void *tmp = realloc (grades, 2 * allocated * sizeof *grades);
        if (!tmp) { /* validate reallocation */
            perror ("realloc-grades");
            break;  /* don't exit, original pointer still good */
        }
        grades = tmp;       /* assign reallocated block to grades */
        allocated *= 2;     /* update allocated size */
    }

    /* fill next element -- keep going.... */
    used++;
}
```

Look things over and let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: Umm... OK, which one? He has `grades` to the array, and then `tmp` to reallocate -- what else does he need?

Comment: sadly I have to do this in a much more basic way. I can't use perror or void *tmp or realloc. we can only use the most basic parts of the language taught in class. I know that doesn't help much but I don't really know the language well enough to explain what I mean. we have to use basic for or while loops. I can't use realloc as said before. I can't use NSTRUCT 8. I don't know what that is to be honest. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not a problem change `void *tmp` to `struct student_grades *tmp` and `perror` to `fputs ("error: malloc-grades.\n", stderr);`. You can use `NSTRUCT` it is nothing but an integer constant. You could just put `size_t  allocated = 8,` (same thing) just sloppy use of a *magic number* instead of a "defined constant". Everything above is basic plain-jane vanilla C. The only headers involved are `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h` -- you can't get more basic.

Comment: we havnt been taught fputs or stderr so i dont think something like that would be accepted on a test. Im trying to find a way that would satisfy the professor. Sadly I dont think I could use any of this but thank you for trying to help.

Comment: basically we write the function and he has test cases that it's tested with on a browser-based program called vocarium.

Comment: OK, answer me this --- "Are you going to assign the return from the function to your pointer after its size was doubled by the function?" -- or -- "Do you want to pass the address-of the original pointer to the function to have it updated internally?" You can do it either way, all will involve the same functions (there isn't any way to do it otherwise in C without implementing your own memory manager an manipulating the program `brk` -- which obviously isn't what was intended.

Comment: Also `void add_grade (struct student_grades *student, int assignment_grade)` can only be used if your array is declared *globally* (bad practice), otherwise if a reallocation occurs within `add_grade` there is no way to return the new address for your array from the function. You must also have a *global* counter as well since your function neither takes a pointer to a counter or returns a value. Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we know what your code expects.

Comment: He needs to grow the array function `add_grade` which currently takes array as a pointer.

Comment: @Joshua that was unclear, but regardless we will need more information in the question before you can `realloc (student->grades_array, ...` Specifically, it is unclear what the members `grades_array_pos` holds (presumably the index of the next grade to add) and similarly `grades_array_size` (presumably an allocation size -- but to what). `int *grades_array[10];` is an *array of pointers to int [10]*. Each pointer could point to a separate allocated block of memory. `grades_array_pos` and `grades_array_size` is insufficient to track the allocation size of each. A MCVE is needed.